# How to get data from JS Guillotine and use it for displaying image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to build some sort of Facebook coverphoto system. Users on my website can upload a photo, which they can drag, scale, etc. I'm using [JS Guillotine](http://guillotine.js.org/) for this, since it's the best script I could find related to Facebook coverphoto system.

So I've implemented the script and everything works like it should, also all the data is being visible on the page. I can store the exact info in a MySQL table with PHP, so all of that works.

But I don't quite understand how the demo page comes up with (for example)

```
style="left:-2.38%";
```

when the demo page displays x = 10. What math or formula do I have to use to come up with those percents? I want to use that info to store in my database, and reposition the image with CSS.

I hope I'm clear enough. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the container is 420 pixels wide and the element needs to be placed 10 pixels from the left border. 10 / 4.2 * 1% =  2.38%

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for. Then, how can I actieve this info with a parent div that is responsive (width 100%)?

Comment: As long as you work with percentages, responsiveness will be ok.